# Unable to get Department Name , Manager etc using Microsoft Graph API C# Code

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using below code :

```
  using Microsoft.Graph;
    using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
    using System;

    namespace MSGraphAPI
    {
        class Program
        {


            private static string clientId = "XXX";


            private static string tenantID = "XXXX";


            private static string objectId = "XXXX";


            private static string clientSecret = "XXXXX";

            static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
            {

                int Flag = 0;
                var tenantId = "XXX.onmicrosoft.com";

                var clientId = "XXXXX";

                var clientSecret = "XXXXX"; // Or some other secure place.

                var scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

                // Configure the MSAL client as a confidential client
                var confidentialClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(clientId)
                    .WithAuthority($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/XXX.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0")
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .Build();


                GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient =
                    new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) => {

            // Retrieve an access token for Microsoft Graph (gets a fresh token if needed).
            var authResult = await confidentialClient
                .AcquireTokenForClient(scopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            // Add the access token in the Authorization header of the API request.
            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
                    })
                    );


                var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();


                do
                {
                            foreach (User user in users)
                            {    

                            Console.WriteLine(user.DisplayName);
                            Console.WriteLine(user.MobilePhone);
                            Console.WriteLine(user.BusinessPhones);
                            Console.WriteLine(user.DirectReports);
                            Console.WriteLine(user.Manager);    
                            var directoryObject = await graphClient.Users[user.userPrincipalName].Manager
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();

  foreach (User user1 in directoryObject )
                        {
// unable to print using user1.displayName

                        }
                            }
                        }
                        while (users.NextPageRequest != null && (users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);

                        Console.WriteLine("------");

            }
        }
    }
```

But, i am unable to fetch directReports or any of the user, i am able to fetch DisplayName etc.
Permission for user.Read etc is already provided in Azure app registration  Portal.
I have tried user.manager also to print the details but unable to print the value. I have attached screenshot also of  app access.

```
var directoryObject = await graphClient.Users["{id|userPrincipalName}"].Manager
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

directoryObject shows the displayName in debug mode but unable to print the displayName as directoryObject.displayName.

Please Help, as i am unable to fetch the required  detail.

Comment: Please try to convert  ```directoryObject```  to  ```User```.

Comment: Take a look at the answer, if it is helpful,  you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure that the user has a manager. You can use the [Microsoft Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) to check it.

[image]

Then, you need to call `graphClient.Users["{id|userPrincipalName}"].Manager` to get the manager.

```
var user =  graphServiceClient.Users["user@XX.onmicrosoft.com"].Request().GetAsync().Result;
            var manager = (User) graphServiceClient.Users["user@XX.onmicrosoft.com"].Manager.Request().GetAsync().Result;
            Console.WriteLine("user_displayName: "+user.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine("manager_displayName: "+manager.DisplayName);
```

[image]

Comment: is there also flag is the specific user is a Manager?
Say for example you have the list of subordinates (directReports), can you also get also the subordinates from the subordinates? (employee-manager-manager (this user is active) (without checking for each user the directReports endpoint)